# Adobe Illustrator: How to create a clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, mask, path, pathfinder

I have this logo I am working on. I have 2 questions:

1) I have a white circle behind the 4. I'd like to use that circle as a clipping mask for the 4 so that the 4 fits perfectly within that white circle. How can I do this?

2) After that, if I wanted to paint the 5 areas in white (between blue and green) each a different color, how can I isolate those areas to paint?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a clipping mask, grab the circle and bring it to the front, select it and the 4, right click and choose create clipping mask.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use "Divide" in the Pathfinder palette (which used to be called "Mix Hard"). Make sure you select your circle and choose Object → Outline Paths so your circle is not a line-with-stroke, select the circle and the four, bring up the Pathfinder palette, and choose Divide (first button on the lower left).

For the five white areas, just draw shapes behind them which overlap the edges and color the shapes, then send to back.

Answer (score 0):

To paint the 5 areas the easiest way is to select the 4 and your circle and then click the livepaint button... You should be able to color these areas independently and very easily. When finished you can expand the whole and get the colored shapes ready for aditional editing. 
You can achieve the same thing with the pathfinder as Lauren Ipsum points out. Livepaint is faster, though